# C - I keep getting segmantation fault with strtok()

Tags: c

I want to make a function that takes a char *, tokenizes it with strtok() and returns a char ** with all the arguements. I keep getting the Segmentation Fault error every time I try to execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



#define LENGTH  10

char ** boom(char * line, int * lng){
    size_t size = strlen(line )+1;
    int tksize = *lng;
    const char d[2] = " ";  
    char a[size];
    memcpy(a, line , size);

    char ** tk = (char**) malloc(tksize*sizeof(char*));
    int i=0;
    char* token = strtok(a, d);
    while(token!=NULL){
        tk[i] = token;
        i++;        
        token = strtok(NULL, d);
    }
    return tk;
 }

int main(void){

    int i, lng = LENGTH;
    char * string = "this is a beutiful message.\0";
    char ** tk = boom(string , &lng);

    for (i=0; i<lng; i++){  
        printf("%s\n", tk[i]);      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need the return type of boom() to be char** so I haven't used a return type of char * []. I suspect it's something the the char** malloc.Thanks for your help.

Comment: `tk[i] = token;` your copy of the string `char a[size];` is in automatic storage. So after return, your tk array will contain pointers to this old memory.

Comment: The return value of `strtok` is a pointer into the string being parsed.  Since `a`'s lifetime is limited to `boom`, so are the pointers you're copying into `tk`.

Comment: Also, `boom` never changes `lng`, so the `for` loop tries to print `LENGTH` strings even if you found fewer.

Comment: so I should memcpy(tk[i], token, strlen(token)+1) ?

Answer (score 1):

You let `strtok` operate on local variable `char a[size]`, so `char* token = strtok(a, d)` will point into memory allocated on the stack. Once function `boom` has finished, this memory will not be valid any more, and that's the reason for the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

`char a[size];` is an array allocated with automatic storage duration, meaning once you return from that function, `a` is deallocated. Since you use `a` rather than `line` with `strtok`, the value returned by function `boom` is an array of pointers to a section of memory that is no longer able to be accessed.

Edit: `strtok` is meant to work with writable strings, so `char * string = "...";` in your `main` function isn't really correct (string literals are not writable), which is probably why you need `a` in the first place. If you use `char string[] = "...";` instead, things will work without any need for array `a` because the characters in the string literal would be copied to an array of sufficient size. You'd simply use `line` instead of `a` in your `boom` function.

If you want it to work with read-only strings as well, you'd need to also allocate every item in the `tk` array as an array of `char` (i.e. `tk[i] = malloc(toklen * sizeof *tk[i]);` in a loop over i=0 to `tksize`):

```
char ** boom(char * line, int * lng){
    size_t toklen;
    int tksize = *lng;
    const char d[2] = " ";

    char ** tk = (char**) malloc(tksize*sizeof(char*));
    int i=0;
    char* token = line;
    while(*token!=0){
        toklen = strcspn(token, d) + 1;
        tk[i] = malloc(toklen * sizeof *tk[i]);
        memcpy(tk[i], token, toklen * sizeof *tk[i]);
        i++;
        token += toklen;
        token += strspn(token, d);
    }
    // If we don't use the entire array, set the length.
    *lng = i;
    return tk;
 }
```